# Error TS2415 in simple Typescript/React class

Tags: reactjs, typescript

TS2415: Class 'MyComponent' incorrectly extends base class

I have created the following code snippet:

```
import * as React from "react";

export interface IMyProps {
}

export interface IMyState {
}

export class MyComponent extends React.Component<IMyProps, IMyState> {
    constructor(props: IMyProps) { 
        super(props);
    }

    render() {

    }
}
```

But the TypeScript compiler gives me the following error:

> (9,14): error TS2415: Class 'MyComponent' incorrectly extends base
>   class 'Component'.   Types of property 'render'
>   are incompatible.
>       Type '() => void' is not assignable to type '() => false | Element'.
>         Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'false | Element'.

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add a return statement to the render method for it to compile:

```
import * as React from "react";

export interface IMyProps {
}

export interface IMyState {
}

export class MyComponent extends React.Component<IMyProps, IMyState> {
    constructor(props: IMyProps) { 
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return <div/> // I had to return a valid return type here.
    }
}
```

I think this is because because the return type is not known until the return statement has been interpreted. 
Until then, the render() method gets interpreted as returning 'void'.